# syntax for linux/unix command "column"

Tags: linux, unix

Manpages for the command "column" show:

```
column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]

 -s      Specify a set of characters to be used to delimit
         columns for the -t option.
```

I could not find out howto use parameter "-s".
Can anybody give a syntax example with "-s"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ column -t -s'*' <<< 'a*b*c'
a  b  c
```